# Using download.file to download a zip file from URL in R

Tags: r, curl, libcurl, rcurl

I am trying to use download.file to extract a zip file from a URL and then push all the data in each of the files into a MySQL database.  I am getting stuck in the first step where I use download.file to extract the zip file

I have tried the following but to no avail

```
myURL = paste("https://onedrive.live.com/download.aspx?cid=D700ACC18C0F37E6&resid=D700ACC18C0F37E6%2118670&ithint=%2Ezip",sep = "")
download.file(url=myURL,destfile=zippedFile, method='auto')

myURL = paste("https://onedrive.live.com/download.aspx?cid=D700ACC18C0F37E6&resid=D700ACC18C0F37E6%2118670&ithint=%2Ezip",sep = "")
download.file(url=myURL,destfile=zippedFile, method='curl')
```

Please suggest where am I going wrong.  Also some pointers on how to take one file at a time from the zip folder and push into a DB will be most helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What finally worked in AWS is the use of the package downloader

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/downloader/downloader.pdf

It has features to support https.  Hope it will help someone

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
myURL = paste("https://onedrive.live.com/download.aspx?cid=D700ACC18C0F37E6&resid=D700ACC18C0F37E6%2118670&ithint=%2Ezip",sep = "")

dir = "zippedFile.zip"
download.file(myURL, dir, mode="wb")
```

> destfile -- a character string with the name where the downloaded file
>   is saved. Tilde-expansion is performed.

Comment: Your method will give  error. Error in download.file(myURL, dir) : unsupported URL scheme

Comment: I just added `mode="wb"` and now its working on my end.

Comment: It works in my local machine but not when I run my R from AWS.  Any suggestions

Comment: I wish I could help, but I don't have any experience with AWS, sorry.

Comment: @SushantaDeb Does your AWS machine has the SSL support in curl? I am not knowledgeable about R, but libcurl must be built with SSL support and openssl (or whatever SSL library is used) might need to be installed for it to work. Does `curl --help` list https as supported protocol on AWS?